# I have a image saved in data base how can I open this image with a op and save as dialog box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, request, response

C# WPF Application : I have a image saved in my database that i am reading as a byte stream
this part is done 
My Question is How can I open this image with a open/save as dialog box. Like the one that appears in web browsers.

For Example In Dialog Box if the User Click Open word, pdf or image file should directly open otherwise if he clicks on save as it should open a Save as Dialog Box..

Please support...

This is the Dialog that i want to appear in my application
First Image on the [link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET)

Comment: use the SaveFileDialog! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the save file dialog in the Microsoft.Win32 namespace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

when the save is pressed, you get the result for it. (ShowDialog() actually) and when it is OK/yes then proceed to save the image read from the DB to the path and filename the user selected

take a look at this too:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-savefiledialog/

I am also unsure but I think you can still use the System.Windows.Forms SaveFileDialog too but will make your app a little bloated as you need the System.Windows.Forms assembly in order to access it.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed Ilyas for support, i am able to get the save file dialog but... to elaborate more about my requirement i have added a link the dialog in that link is what i want...

Comment: I see. in which case you cannot as that is for a WEB platform whilst WPF is a DESKTOP platform - different altogether. The only thing for you to do if you want it like so then is to create a custom dialog that looks like what you are looking for and every browser displays it differently.

Comment: In this case can i directly open file with its default application

Comment: again as I have said, it is not possible to have a dialog like the webplatform unless you create your own from scratch.